# Custom ILogicalThreadAffinitive Class Object is Null on Postback

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, nullreferenceexception

A former employee implemented a custom VB.Net Context class that inherits DictionaryBase and implements ILogicalThreadAffinitive. The class object maintains values such as user ID, language, location, etc. throughout the user's session in an ASP.NET web application with .NET 4 Framework.

```
<Serializable()> _
Public NotInheritable Class Context
    Inherits DictionaryBase
    Implements ILogicalThreadAffinative

    ... Class Methods ...

End Class
```

The object class seems to work fine, holding the values as expected when navigating from page to page, even when loading a popup page. My issue arises anytime I have a PostBack action. When this occurs, the object becomes null and causes null reference errors.

The strange part is that it works for everyone except me. It's installed on our client's system, runs in our test environment, and works for our other developer on the project, but there's something preventing it from working in my development environment, which hosts the application with the local IIS 7.0 web server. The other developer and I have cross-checked all of the local IIS settings, VS2010 settings, and internet options that we would have altered, but everything appears to be identical between the two machines (both Win7 x64, building the application in x86 mode). Needless to say, this issue has become very prohibitive for development and troubleshooting issues.

Are there any suggestions as to what else can be checked that might produce such behavior?

**EDIT**: After some more advanced digging, it appears the PostBack is causing a request to fire on a second thread. This second thread, despite what documentation seems to say, does not carry over the values in the CallContext. On my colleague's *working* environment, this request is handled on the same thread. This seems to be the main symptom of the problem, but we still cannot pinpoint the source. Also, perhaps of note: my machine has an SSD and the other developer does not. I don't know if that affects threading, but I don't think it would produce these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not particularly satisfied with the solution, but I was able to run the program without errors by switching to the ASP.NET v4 Classic Application Pool. As stated before, my colleague's machine is running the program just fine with the Integrated Application Pool. On my machine, however, this causes threading issues.

So, not a satisfactory "answer" per se; but I have a solution, nonetheless.